# Fixing bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'

Tags: bash

I have a bash syntax error problem. I am writing a script to insert information in files without opening the file like so

```
for i in 1 2 3 do echo This is a sample text > sample-$i.txt done
```

But it gives the following error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

Why is that? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing two semicola. This is the fixed version:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do echo This is a sample text > sample-$i.txt; done
```

Comment: "Semicola"? :) I've never seen the Greek plural applied to that before.

Comment: Although technically, there are *two*, so it should be in the dual: semicolo.

Answer (score -1):

Appending data to the file doesn't require opening the file.  One of the greatest things with Linux scripting is the way that data can be piped around and into/out of files.

`>` will empty the file but `>>` will append to the file

Comment: I think the question was not about appending.

Comment: It is very vague

Comment: Also, appending still opens the file, it just doesn't truncate it first.